# Coinbase API Request in Ruby always returns Invalid API Key

Tags: ruby, coinbase-api

I am trying to learn how to make simple requests to the Coinbase API in Ruby.  This is mostly for my own entertainment and education.  The Ruby GEM is so out of date I thought I'd start working on my own system instead of relying on it.  To that end I wanted to get the basics working before I tried to turn it into a gem.

Here is the beginnings of my module.

And no matter what, when I try to get `/accounts` I get a 401 response.

`@status=401 @reason_phrase="Unauthorized" @response_body="{\"message\":\"Invalid API Key\"}`

```rb
# Simple Coinbase Requests
require 'base64'
require 'openssl'
require 'json'
require 'faraday'

module Coinbase
  module Request
    class API
      def initialize key = '', secret = '', passphrase = '', sandbox = false
        @url = sandbox ? 'https://api-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com' : 'https://api-public.pro.coinbase.com'
        @key = key
        @secret = secret
        @passphrase = passphrase
        @content_type = 'application/json'
      end

      # Get Accounts
      def accounts
        self.get '/accounts'
      end


      # Do the work of a HTTP Get
      def get path
        timestamp = Time.now.to_i.to_s
        headers = auth_headers path, '', 'GET', timestamp

        connection = Faraday.new(url: 'https://api-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com', headers: headers, ssl: { :verify => false })
        # puts connection.inspect

        connection.get path
      end

      # Auth Headers
      # CB-ACCESS-KEY The api key as a string.
      # CB-ACCESS-SIGN The base64-encoded signature (see Signing a Message).
      # CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP A timestamp for your request.
      # CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE The passphrase you specified when
      def auth_headers path = '', body = '', method = 'GET', timestamp = nil
        {
          'Content-Type': 'Application/JSON',
          'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': self.signature(path, body, method, timestamp),
          'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
          'CB-ACCESS-KEY': @key,
          'CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE': @passphrase
        }
      end

      # Generate a signature
      def signature path = '', body = '', method = 'GET', timestamp = nil
        body = body.to_json if body.is_a?(Hash)
        secret = Base64.decode64 @secret
        hash = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest 'sha256', secret, "#{timestamp}#{method}#{path}#{body}"
        Base64.strict_encode64 hash
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm calling it using the following (THE KEY/SECRET/PASSPHRASE ARE FAKE for this example)

```rb
coinbase = Coinbase::Request::API.new('123426bc3a583fb8393141fb7777fake',
                                      '+FAKEbGoG1eT1WVFWNJxFtTE/y4kIYq2Lbf6FAKEw5j2756GXgaqg5iXTsqPJXKkStZ7nPoTT2RGKwiJfRFAKE==',
                                      'FAKEPASSPHRASE',
                                      true)
puts coinbase.accounts.inspect
```

The signature "what" (as defined as "#{timestamp}#{method}#{path}#{body}" in your docs) for this simple request would be something like `1624063589GET/accounts`

The headers come out to `{:"Content-Type"=>"Application/JSON", :"CB-ACCESS-SIGN"=>"rs29GSZuRspthioywb5IkaHQmPIwH5DRDW5LHoYUvw8=", :"CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP"=>"1624063726", :"CB-ACCESS-KEY"=>"123426bc3a583fb8393141fb22328113", :"CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE"=>"FAKEPASSPHRASE"}`

Once connected the headers come out as seen below in the faraday response object.

This is the full response object output which is what I would expect to get with fake keys as used but I get the same thing when I use the keys I generated here: https://pro.coinbase.com/profile/ap

```rb
#<Faraday::Response:0x00000001621a8e58 @on_complete_callbacks=[], @env=#<Faraday::Env @method=:get @url=#<URI::HTTPS https://api-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com/accounts> @request=#<Faraday::RequestOptions (empty)> @request_headers={"Content-type"=>"Application/JSON", "Cb-access-sign"=>"vEfjUnFy+3qQqRa2lxvEC5O32xOa6t7NgGAxO8OYrpo=", "Cb-access-timestamp"=>"1624063280", "Cb-access-key"=>"123426bc3a583fb8393141fb22328113", "Cb-access-passphrase"=>"FAKEPASSPHRASE", "User-Agent"=>"Faraday v1.4.2"} @ssl=#<Faraday::SSLOptions (empty)> @response=#<Faraday::Response:0x00000001621a8e58 ...> @response_headers={"date"=>"Sat, 19 Jun 2021 00:41:21 GMT", "content-type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "content-length"=>"29", "connection"=>"keep-alive", "access-control-allow-headers"=>"Content-Type, Accept, cb-session, cb-fp, cb-form-factor", "access-control-allow-methods"=>"GET,POST,DELETE,PUT", "access-control-allow-origin"=>"*", "access-control-expose-headers"=>"cb-before, cb-after, cb-gdpr", "access-control-max-age"=>"7200", "cache-control"=>"no-store", "etag"=>"W/\"1d-mmRSeO9uba2rhQtGfy4YjixIkt4\"", "strict-transport-security"=>"max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains", "x-content-type-options"=>"nosniff", "x-dns-prefetch-control"=>"off", "x-download-options"=>"noopen", "x-frame-options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "x-xss-protection"=>"1; mode=block", "cf-cache-status"=>"MISS", "cf-request-id"=>"0ac3501f6300005ae1c99c3000000001", "expect-ct"=>"max-age=604800, report-uri=\"https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct\"", "vary"=>"Accept-Encoding", "server"=>"cloudflare", "cf-ray"=>"6618b6123ba75ae1-IAD"} @status=401 @reason_phrase="Unauthorized" @response_body="{\"message\":\"Invalid API Key\"}">>
```

I've been plugging away at this for days and I just can't seem to get it to not return `Invalid API Key`.  I feel like I'm so very close.. but no cigar..

Thoughts?

NOTE: On a whim before submitting this I tried `/currencies` and it worked fine.

Comment: The `/currencies` endpoint does not require authorization.

Answer (score 3):

It took me some trial and error with this too, but I was hitting invalid signature errors rather than invalid API key errors. Maybe this will help anyway:

Working example:

`Gemfile`

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.6.7'
gem 'httparty'
```

`coinbase.rb`

```
require 'base64'
require 'httparty'

API_KEY = ''  
API_PASSPHRASE = '' 
API_SECRET = ''
key = Base64.decode64(API_SECRET)

url = "https://api.exchange.coinbase.com"
requestPath = "/accounts"
method = "GET"
body = ""

timestamp = Time.now.to_i.to_s
message = timestamp + method + requestPath + body
hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', key, message)
signature = Base64.strict_encode64(hmac)

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': signature,
    'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
    'CB-ACCESS-KEY': API_KEY,
    'CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE': API_PASSPHRASE
}

result = HTTParty.get(url+requestPath, headers: headers)
puts result.response.body
```

Run:

```
bundle install
bundle exec coinbase.rb
```

Comment: I finally found the same solution, so can confirm.  Bounty was not cancelable, so it's yours!